# Plotting and Interpreting TensorFlow Results

Tags: python, tensorflow

**The Problem:**
I'm having trouble plotting and interpreting the results from my TensorFlow model. I've created my own CSV of [x, y, color] where there is a plot of randomly scattered dots with a clear pattern in the color formation. I'm able to enter all the data into the model and train the neural network but can't seem to put it all together. I'm a bit new to this as a hobbyist.

Essentially I want the ML algorithm to pick up the pattern from 100 datapoints and use it on a test dataset of nodes to plot an approximation of the pattern.

**The Code:**

```
LABEL_COLUMN = "Color"

LABELS=[0,1]

def get_dataset(data_url, **kwargs):
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        data_url,
        batch_size=5,
        label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
        na_value="?",
        num_epochs=1,
        ignore_errors=True,
        **kwargs)
    return dataset

project_data = get_dataset(data_url)
project_test_data = get_dataset(test_data_url)

def pack(features,label):
    return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=-1), label

packed_data = project_data.map(pack)
packed_test_data = project_test_data.map(pack)

model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model2.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer = "adam",
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)

model2.fit(packed_data, epochs=100)

model_output = model2.predict(packed_test_data)
model_output.plot()
```

**Gives the below error:**
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: I believe the output of model2.predict is a numpy array. In order to plot a numpy array, you can use matplotlib.pyplot. Here is an example: https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/ 

Let me know if you need starter code!

Comment: Thank you! This is a great site. I've converted to numpy. Still working my way through learning the different datatypes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this function can be adapted to solve your problem?

(From https://jonchar.net/notebooks/Artificial-Neural-Network-with-Keras/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_decision_boundary(X, y, model, steps=1000, cmap='Paired'):
    """
    Function to plot the decision boundary and data points of a model.
    Data points are colored based on their actual label.
    """
    cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap)

    # Define region of interest by data limits
    xmin, xmax = X[:,0].min() - 1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    ymin, ymax = X[:,1].min() - 1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    steps = 1000
    x_span = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, steps)
    y_span = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, steps)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_span, y_span)

    # Make predictions across region of interest
    labels = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Plot decision boundary in region of interest
    z = labels.reshape(xx.shape)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, z, cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5)

    # Get predicted labels on training data and plot
    train_labels = model.predict(X)
    ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y, cmap=cmap, lw=0)

    return fig, ax

plot_decision_boundary(X, y, model, cmap='RdBu')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great start I've used to get on my feet. Still trying to work out some of the data transforms from CSV files but for arrays I'm generating with for loops this works perfectly!